# Why would the activity date for a contribution differ from the contribution date?

Tags: civicontribute

Using CiviCRM 4.6.33 on Drupal 7.56. I just noticed, while adding a contribution to this person's record, that for a contribution made on December 31 of last year (2016), the contribution date and the activity date for that contribution do not match. The activity date shows as December 31, 2017, which is 10 days from now.

I was going to report this as a bug, but I have checked donations made by other people on December 31, 2016, and they do not seem to have the same problem. I must have done something to make this happen, I suppose, but I see no way to manually change the activity date.

Here are screenshots of the contributions and activities windows.

[image: Contributions window]
[image: Activities window]

Comment: To confirm, was this contribution added manually or processed automatically?

Comment: This was a paper check that we received in the mail, and the transaction was entered manually.

Answer (score 1):

Is possible that you first entered wrong date while creating contribution and then updated receive date by editing the Contribution?

There is no form to update the Contribution activity. But you do this using api explorer screen.

1. First retrieve the Activity ID using Contribution Id(source record id)
   [image]
   (here 689 is Activity ID and 128 is Contribution Id)
2. Update the Activity date.
   [image]

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Thanks, Pradeep. API Explorer is not something I'm familiar with, but my IT guy knows about it. I appreciate the details. I'll pass that along.